# Jetty Embedded Server and Spring Security integration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to log-in using Spring Security, my code has worked when I'm using jetty maven plugin. But now I want it to work when run on Jetty Embedded Server too. When I submit the log-in to spring security processing link, it show this warning:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
RequestURI=/auth/login_check
Caused by:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:290)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:290)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:209)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:194)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.applySessionFixation(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication(AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:32)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:216)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:361)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:534)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:879)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:741)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:213)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:403)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:522)
```

I'm guessing it conflict with jsp-2.1, jsp-api-2.1 jar of Jetty. What could I do to fix this? This is my jetty dependency:

```
<properties>
    <jetty.version>6.1.14</jetty.version>
</properties>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--jsp support for jetty, add the 2 following -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring security config in dispatcher servlet xml:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password"
        login-processing-url="/auth/login_check" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout"
        logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <security:remember-me token-validity-seconds="1209600"
        remember-me-parameter="remember-me" data-source-ref="dataSource" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select email, password, enabled from users where email=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username=?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chamgroupdb" />
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value=""></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.factory">validator</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.chamgroup.model" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade Jetty for this to work.

[`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#changeSessionId--) was introduced in Servlet 3.1.

Jetty 6 is Servlet 2.4 - and was EOL (End of Life) in 2010

Jetty 7 is Servlet 2.5 - and was EOL in 2014

Jetty 8 is Servlet 3.0 - and was EOL in 2014

Jetty 9.0 - 9.1 were releases based on early draft/alpha/beta releases of the  Servlet 3.1 spec

Jetty 9.2.x was the first version to support the final Servlet 3.1 spec

Jetty 9.3.2 is the current stable version of Jetty (and requires Java 8)

Comment: thanks for the infomation about Servlet of each version